# Problem selecting Vim version:

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use ubuntu 12.04.

I want to install the latest version of Vim(7.3) with all its important plugins. So, which version of Vim should I install?: Vim or Vim-Gnome or Vim-athena or any other version?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your desktop environment. For GUI best variant is vim-gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim is the console version.  to install it,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

But if you like a GUI based vim, then install vim-gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Vim-athena, is another form of GUI based vim, to install

```
sudo apt-get install vim-athena
```

Each has its own dependencies, and it comes to preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about gui then [vim-nox](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/vim-nox) is your best option:

> a version of vim compiled with support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI.

Otherwise `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk` will give you a similar build with gui support.